# Show/Hide div using href and scroll to displayed div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery function that shows/hides div upon `href` link click. But everytime the `div` loads, the page scrolls up to the top instead of the target div. Here is the jquery code and the html layout for `div`s. The jquery is used to get the id from the clicked link and open target div.

I need the page to scroll to the target div upon click.

so if i click on `item1` then page scrolls to `div100` then when i click on `item1-desc1` then page should scroll to `div1`.

is there a way to edit the jquery to achieve this.

i have tried to use the following inside the click function. but the page does not scroll to the target div.

```
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('#') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
```

```js
$('a').click(function () {
var divname= this.name;
$("#"+divname).fadeIn("slow").siblings().fadeOut("fast");
});
```

```html
<a href="#" name="div100" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item1</font></a>
<a href="#" name="div200" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item2</font></a>
<a href="#" name="div300" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item3</font></a>
<a href="#" name="div400" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item4</font></a>

<div id="div100" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div1" >item1-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div2" >item1-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div3" >item1-desc3</a></li1>
  
<div id="div200" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div4" > item2-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div5" >item2-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div6" >item2-desc3</a></li1>
    
<div id="div300" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div7" > item3-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div8" >item3-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div9" >item3-desc3</a></li1>
      
<div id="div400" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div10" > item4-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div11" >item4-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div12" >item4-desc3</a></li1>
  
<div id="div1" style="display:none" align="left">
  <!--div1 contents-->
<div id="div2" style="display:none" align="left">
  <!--div2 contents-->
<div id="div3" style="display:none" align="left">
  <!--div3 contents-->
<div id="div4" style="display:none" align="left">
  <!--div4 contents-->
  <!--- so on...->
```

Comment: Stop default link action using `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: this would not do anything. the links dont work when i used the above line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try was good, you just put the wrong attr:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
   }, 500);
```

And you should add a preventDefault:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).fadeIn("slow").siblings().fadeOut("fast");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code once before as well. it would not do anything. the links on the page don't bring up anything. @shwarp

Comment: oh yeah sorry I didn't watch your html carrefully: you need to put in the href the id of the div you want to go to, like `<a href='#div100'></a>` , but if you don't watn to do that, you can replace `$(this).attr('href')` by `$("#"+divname)`

Comment: it actually works. thanks a lot. i was trying various plugins and this was such a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `href` attribute in `a` elements to include the target id:

```
<a href="#div100" name="div100" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item1</font></a>

<li1><a href="#div1" name="div1" >item1-desc1</a></li1>
```

This will add an anchor to the element with the id in the href. So this way you can remove:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('#') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
return false;
```